# Can I be notified when a user drags a control away from the MainWindow?

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a stackpanel holding a group of buttons in my WPF program.  I set it up so that the user can drag and drop the buttons to re-order them.  I would also like the user to be able to drag a button away somewhere to remove it from the stackpanel.  This could mean that the user is dragging the button to a completely different window (like Windows Explorer or Google Chrome or the Desktop).

Is this possible?  Can my code be notified when the user releases (drops) the button while the mouse is over another program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can check the value that is returned from DragDrop.DoDragDrop(...).  I call it like this:

```
var result = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, this, DragDropEffects.Move);
```

It looks like if `result == DragDropEffects.None`, then the user dropped the button off the window.